# Server 2008 File and Print Services fails after a period of time

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

We have replaced several Server 2003 file and print servers with Server 2008 Enterprise. The file and print services work fine for a couple of weeks then suddenly, nobody can access the network shares or the printers on that server and a reboot is required to resolve the issue. This is happening on several servers which were all fine with 2003. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to check the Event Log? There might be some hints there as to what is wrong.

Comment: I've quickly rant through it but did not see anything that stood out and said, "I'm the problem".